# How to generate a new file by extracting some parts?

Tags: text-processing, sed, macos

My initial logs file extract is as follows:

```
b6227|—|  Thermometer:  CRC matched: computed: 36 == read: 36
b6227|—| SocEvaluator: Final SoC is following to midle range, aka: SoC 64.5537%
b6227|—| SocEvaluator:  Final SoC is 64.5537%
b6227|—| SocEvaluator: Final SoC is following to midle range, aka: SoC 64.5552%
```

From which I'd like to create a new csv for rendering curves in Excel. The CSV file should look like this:

```
64.5537
```

I tried this but didn't make it:

```bash
sed -nr 's/ Final SoC is (\d\.\d%)/\1/gp' ~/extremeCold.20220926.log > final.csv
```

What's wrong?

[UPDATE]

I am running on macOS Monterey (v12.5)

The very number to keep is 64.5537 from the line `b6227|—| SocEvaluator:  Final SoC is 64.5537%` (for you guys having read the before update question, forget about the 64.5536. It was simply the next available SoC).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain, in words as well as by example, what numbers should be chosen from the file.  Where does the `64.5536` come from? Should we only look at lines containing the string `Final SoC`? Do we _need_ to use ? And what operating system are you using? We need to know to know what tools are available.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help

Comment: I assume then, the second line of your desired output should actually be `64.5552`, not `64.5557`?

Comment: Nope, one must only keep `b6227|—| SocEvaluator:  Final SoC is ` pattern (aka 64.5537 here)and ignore the others lines

Comment: 2 lines, each containing a number, isn't a CSV, it's just a text file. A CSV would have Comma Separated Values on each line. It's not at all obvious why your output would not include `64.5552` given  the last line of input is `b6227|—| SocEvaluator: Final SoC is following to midle range, aka: SoC 64.5552%`.

Comment: You seem to only have one line matching your requirement(s), yet you show two lines of predicted (filtered) output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` on Monterey 12.6

```
$ sed -En '/.* SocEvaluator:  Final SoC is ([0-9.]+)%.*$/s//\1/pwfinal.csv' input_file
64.5537
$ cat final.csv
64.5537
```

Comment: One thing to note: I imported the source file from a colleague working on Windows. I noticed the file is CRLF terminated, which makes the sed not woking. I had to replace by LF. Is there a way to tell sed to handle CRLF as the end of line?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Unfortunately, I cannnot answer that at this time without importing a similar file myself and testing as I use WSL Linux for files imported from Windows and not the mac. Have you managed to find a solution for the line endings?

Answer (score 1):

This is using `sed` to match the wanted line(s) and then chop off everything up to the last space:

```bash
sed -e '/SocEvaluator:.*Final SoC is [[:digit:]]/!d' -e 's/.* //' file
```

For the given data, this would output

```
64.5537%
```

To remove the `%` character:

```bash
sed -e '/SocEvaluator:.*Final SoC is [[:digit:]]/!d' -e 's/.* //' -e 's/%$//' file
```

Using `awk` with exactly the same detecting regular expression, and then printing the last field on each line that this expression matches:

```bash
awk '/SocEvaluator:.*Final SoC is [[:digit:]]/ { print $NF }' file
```

Removing the `%` sign before printing:

```bash
awk '/SocEvaluator:.*Final SoC is [[:digit:]]/ { sub("%$","",$NF); print $NF }' file
```

The regular expression

```
SocEvaluator:.*Final SoC is [[:digit:]]
```

... would match any line that contains the text `SocEvaluator:` followed later by the text `Final SoC is`  and a digit.

Note that `sed` and `awk` on macOS do not understand Perl-compatible regular expressions like `\d`. Related to this point: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905)

Comment: GNU `sed` doesn't recognise `\d` either. ast-open's `sed` does (and `-r`, initially a GNUism, BSD and soon-standard equivalent being `-E`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I tweaked that point a bit in response to your comment. I'm a bit unfamiliar what expressions GNU tools usually support.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put $<> if m/ "Final SoC is " <(\d* \. \d*)> /;'  file

#OR
 
~$ raku -ne 'put $0 if m/ "Final SoC is " (\d* \. \d*) /;' file
```

Sample Input:

```
b6227|—|  Thermometer:  CRC matched: computed: 36 == read: 36
b6227|—| SocEvaluator: Final SoC is following to midle range, aka: SoC 64.5537%
b6227|—| SocEvaluator:  Final SoC is 64.5537%
b6227|—| SocEvaluator: Final SoC is following to midle range, aka: SoC 64.5552%
```

Sample Output:

```
64.5537
```

In the first example, Raku's capture markers `<( … )>` are used to drop the "Final SOC..." text from the match object, and the remaining capture is output using the `$<>` (or synonymous `$/`) match variable, subject to an `if` conditional.

In the second example, parentheses are used to capture a portion of the match into match-variable `$<>.[0]` which is the same as match-variable `$/.[0]` which is the same as `$0`. This `$0` capture is out`put`, subject to an `if` conditional.

https://raku.org